# Customize iPhone camera UI using PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap. I am prototyping a project and am just wondering if it's possible to achieve a feature with PG.

When I call the camera on an iPhone it open up a camera stream with the stand camera UI. Is it possible to customize the UI to the way I want. To be more specific, instead of the one action button on the bottom, can I replace it with three custom buttons, and they all capture an image from the camera stream and then save the thumbnail onto the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but requires changes to PhoneGap core in objective-c. Take a look at the camera.m and the camera.h file in your PhoneGap lib. You can modify them as needed.

Comment: Is it possible to structure this as a phoneGap plugin, rather than make changes to the core? Perhaps basing your code on the core camera code but calling it cameraPlus or something?

Comment: Is there any chance for an example?